# HttpSessionListener doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

I have implemented HttpSessionListiner but it doesn't work.
Checked it with debuger - new session creates after entering servlet, JSESSION_ID changes after login, but session.getCreateTime() stays the same(session stays the same?).
Using annotations, Spring Security. Maybe i missed some config in spring security?

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@WebListener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static int totalActiveSessions;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SessionListener.class);  

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        totalActiveSessions++;
        log.warn("sessionCreated - add one session into counter");
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        totalActiveSessions--;
        log.debug("sessionDestroyed - deleted one session from counter");
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using spring-security in your project?

Comment: @NallaSrinivas Yes, but i tried to implement this listener in other project, that doesn't use Spring Security, it doesn't work too.

Comment: extend org.springframework.security.web.session. ttpSessionEventPublisher if you are using spring security and specify this listener in web.xml. if you are not using spring security then check servlet api version, for you it should be 3.0

Comment: @NallaSrinivas tried to extend HttpSessionEventPublisher, nothing changed. I'm using annotations and SpringBoot. Servlet-api 3.1.0

Comment: have you sprecified ttpSessionEventPublisher in web.xml?. also check spring security filter in web.xml. if you are using spring security then <b>SessionListener</b> should be extended from ttpSessionEventPublisher and override two methods.

Comment: @NallaSrinivas i'm not using web.xml in project, only annotations. Annotation "WebListener" should registrate listener. I tried to extend my SessionListener from HttpSessionEventPublisher and override this methods, it doesn't work too.

Comment: register(SessionListener) this bean with spring container..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionListener> sessionListener() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionListener>(new sessionListener());
}
```

This bean registrated my listener. I haven't found another solution.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a session fixation attack, Spring changes the session ID after the user is authenticated. You must also implement `HttpSessionIdListener`:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener, HttpSessionIdListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionListener.class);

    public SessionListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(final HttpSessionEvent event) {
        logIt(event.getSession(), "CREATED  ");
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(final HttpSessionEvent event) {
        logIt(event.getSession(), "DESTROYED");
    }

    private void logIt(HttpSession session, String action) {
        LOGGER.info("{}: {}, {}", action, session.getId(), Long.valueOf(session.getCreationTime()));
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionIdChanged(HttpSessionEvent event, String oldSessionId) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        LOGGER.info("CHANGED  : {} --> {}, {}", oldSessionId, session.getId(), Long.valueOf(session.getCreationTime()));
    }

}
```