# Can't use any kind of SessionListener when using Spring Security in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, spring-security

I have a very basic Spring Security setup using Session. My problem is that I can't find a way to use any kind of Session Listener (both Spring and Servlet API versions) to listen to SessionCreated event. Login is working and session is being created properly.

The reason I need a listener is because I want to initialize certain session attributes (ex. shopping kart, recent items list) so I can access them seamlessly from `@Controller` request mappings, without having to worry whether session attributes are initialized.

Security configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secured/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .rememberMe().key("unique");
    }

    ...
}
```

First, I have tried the most basic session listenter:

```
@Component
public class InitHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have also tried answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739957/httpsessionlistener-doesnt-work), which also didn't work

Comment: Which session created event? Which listeners, how are you registering them?

Comment: I have first tried the most basic way, and it didn't work.

```
@Component
public class InitHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
 public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
  ...
 }
}
```

Then, I tried answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739957/httpsessionlistener-doesnt-work), which also didn't work

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding code as comments that is totally unreadable.

Comment: Is that listener in a package that is properly covered by the component scanning?

Comment: Yes, bean called `initHttpSessionListener` is present in ApplicationContext.

Comment: I also see many session-related beans, since Spring Security is using session, so I suspect something might be overriding my class, but I am not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: Then it should just work (tm), so either there is no session created or there is something else you aren't showing here that disables the listener. Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with *"session-related beans"*?

Comment: By "session-related beans", I mean `httpSessionEventPublisher`, `sessionRepository`, `sessionEventHttpSessionListenerAdapter`, `springSessionRepositoryFilter`, and many others that I haven't manually initialized. Session is being created (I see new session in local database)

Comment: I am using version 2.5.6

Comment: Are you using Spring Session by any change or just Spring Security without Spring Session? If you are using Spring Session than there will not be the creation of a regular HTTP Session. So there is nothing to listen to.

Comment: I am using Spring Security backed with Spring Session JDBC. HttpSession is properly injected in controller methods, I can access it and all properties are properly stored in MySQL DB. There is no way of reacting to session created event.

Comment: What is the proper event to listen to?

Comment: The JDBC integration doesn't support event publishing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554089/session-events-dont-work-in-spring-session?rq=1

Comment: That's a very sad limitation.. Thank you very much for your time!!!

Comment: Please, add it as answer (so I can mark it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what was getting clear from your comments is that you are using [Spring Session JDBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session-jdbc). Due to the nature of JDBC this doesn't support publishing of session events and thus you cannot listen to those events.

As a workaround you could create your own `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and put the logic for filling the `Session` in there. Or listen to an `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` using a Spring event listener (would be a bit harder to get to the session but doable).